# Getting Errors When Downloading Files From SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am running a website, and part of the site is allowing users to upload files to a SQL database, and then download them. The download itself works, but the file is getting corrupted.  Image files cannot be opened, doc files are showing up as blank.  I will attach below my uploading script and my downloading script.

```
  $classid = $_POST['uploadclass'];
$userid = $_SESSION['id'];
$view = $_POST['view']; 

$filename = $_FILES['uploadfile']['name'];
$tmpname = $_FILES['uploadfile']['tmpname'];
$filesize = $_FILES['uploadfile']['size'];
$filetype = $_FILES['uploadfile']['type'];

$fp = fopen($tmpname, 'r');
$content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpname));
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
 $filename = addslashes($filename);
}
$query = "INSERT INTO uploads VALUES('','$filename', '$filetype', '$filesize', '$content', '$userid', '$classid', '$view', 'no')";
$run = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

mysqli_close($connect);
header('location: files.php');
```

Below is the code for my download page.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE id=$id";
$run = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)){
$name = $row['name'];
$type = $row['type'];
$size = $row['size'];
$content = $row['content'];

}
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$name");
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: first i would not suggest to upload files to DB at all. And as for your answer plz first check either file is uploaded succesfully in DB or not. See if it wrote data correctly in there or not.

Comment: Also check for Data type of your column. I am not sure but i think it should be Blob. But I personally do not like idea of uplaoding into DB.

Comment: You're running `addslashes()` on a probably binary file, which is a bad idea anyway, but then not removing them before you download. Better not to put the file in the database in the first place. Move it to the file system and store the path in the database.

Comment: The key feature of these slashes is that they ARE removed when writing into the database - the point is that they are not applied everywhere they have to. mysqli_real_escape_string also does add these slashes - but a bit more, and they are also gone when reading back the files and texts.

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly handling the files and everything else when inserting them into the database. All files that are already there are damaged and probably destroyed.

`addslashes()` is no escaping function for a database. Always use the escaping function that comes with the DB extension you are using. If you are using mysqli, then the correct function must be `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

You should however have a look at prepared statements. These will use an different way of transferring the data that does not need escaping. Do pay attention however to the setting of magic quotes. The preferred setting is OFF, and the recent PHP versions starting with 5.4 have this feature removed already. So you have to deal with escaping the data you insert into the database anyway.